# Ошибка подключения vue-i18n в laravel 5.6

Tags: vue.js, i18n, laravel-5.6

Всем привет!
Пробую подключить i18 для vue.js как описано тут
http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/started.html#html

установив пакет в resources/assets/js/app.js прописал :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
...
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
Vue.use(VueI18n)
```

И использую его в resources/assets/js/components/document_categories/DocumentCategoryEdit.vue:

```
<template>

    <section class="card col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 offset-md-1 offset-lg-2">

        <p>{{ $t("message.hello") }}</p>

   </section>  <!-- class="card" -->

</template>

<script>
    import {bus} from '../../app';
    import appMixin from '../../appMixin';
//    import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'  

    Vue.component('markdown-editor', require('../../components/lib/MarkdownEditor.vue'));
    Vue.component('editor-header', require('../../components/lib/EditorHeader.vue'));
    Vue.component('editor-buttons', require('../../components/lib/EditorButtons.vue'));
//    Vue.use(VueI18n)

    const messages = {
        en: {
            message: {
                hello: 'hello world'
            }
        },
        ru: {
            message: {
                hello: 'Превед медвед'
            }
        }
    }

    // Create VueI18n instance with options
    const i18n = new VueI18n({
        locale: 'ru', // set locale
        messages, // set locale messages
    })

    export default {
        created() {
        ...
```

И в консоле ошибка:

```
app.js:152341 Uncaught ReferenceError: VueI18n is not defined
    at Object.render (app.js:152341)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (app.js:152192)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object._typeof (app.js:4735)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:80447)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:63
    at app.js:66
```

Если раскоментарить 2 строчки с подключением и использованием VueI18n получаю ошибку :

```
app.js:6917 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined"
```

Похоже VueI18n не подключен и во втором случае хотя я полагал что в самом vue-файле его подключать не нужно...

Видимо надо как-то иначе подключить VueI18n в vue-файле?

```
Laravel Framework : 5.6.24
"vue": "^2.5.7"
"vue-i18n": "^7.8.0",
```

Спасибо!

MODIFIED :
Уcпешно установив

```
 npm install vue-i18n --save
```

на команду ( как указал Kosta B)
 получил ошибку :

```
$ npm run build
npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2018-06-12T14_53_02_740Z-debug.log
```

И указанныый файл имеет содержимое :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.1.0
3 info using node@v9.11.1
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: build
4 verbose stack     at run (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:151:19)
4 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:61:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:115:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:418:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:373:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:416:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:364:12
4 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:525:3)
5 verbose cwd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/TasksBs41
6 verbose Linux 4.13.0-45-generic
7 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
8 verbose node v9.11.1
9 verbose npm  v6.1.0
10 error missing script: build
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

А формат команды указан правильно?
Не помню чтобы я использовал такую команду...

Comment: Если `npm install vue-i18n --save` делали, то `npm run build`.

Comment: Посмотрите, плиз, на блок MODIFIED вопроса .

Comment: Теперь `npm install`, это надо было в первую очередь делать.